# jBoss Profile - how?

Tags: java, jboss, profiler

I want to profile my jBoss Apps on a remote server. I've tried the Eclipse TPTP project but with an invoked agent my jBoss Portal doesn't start and it ends in unlimited lines of exceptions.

jProfiler doesn't work either, portal doesn't boot.

Netbeans IDE Profiling seems only to work on local machines or did I missed something?

How do you profile your web apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [VisualVM](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/) from the JDK6 works with JBoss Portal (tested with Portal 2.7.1).

Answer (score 1):

I use [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/overview/) to profile JBoss servers, and not just in development, either - the YourKit agent runs on production servers, with no performance impact until the GUI is attached. Works very well.

Comment: If you have money to buy it, yourkit is indeed very nice.

Comment: Does it have a export functionality? I may want to analyze the data afterwards...